# go back to prev version of Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

by mistake I installed Django 1.7, and now I have compatibilities issues, so I'd like to go back to Django 1.4 but don't know how.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you use [`pip`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `pip` run:

```
pip install django==1.4
```

If you're not using `pip`, install it:

```
easy_install pip
```

and then run the `pip install` command above.

Comment: It is needed to set [`-U`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-U) flag...

Comment: @stalk No it does not; I just tried it and it downgraded from 1.7 to 1.4 using the command above. `-U` is used to upgrade to the latest version, as documented [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-U).